# How to replace/modify a pattern by regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

Assume that I want to modify all patterns in a script, take one line as an example:

```
line = "assert Solution().oddEvenList(genNode([2,1,3,5,6,4,7])) == genNode([2,3,6,7,1,5,4]), 'Example 2'"
```

Notice that function `genNode` is taking `List[int]` as the parameter. What I want is to remove the List, and keep the all the integers in the list, so that the function is actually taking `*nums` as the parameters.

Expecting:

```
line = "assert Solution().oddEvenList(genNode(2,1,3,5,6,4,7)) == genNode(2,3,6,7,1,5,4), 'Example 2'"
```

I've come up with a `re` pattern

```
r"([g][e][n][N][o][d][e][(])([[][0-9\,\s]*[]])([)])"
```

but I am not sure how I could use this... I can't get `re.sub` to work as it requires me to replace with a fixed string.

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/vaxDcU/1 Btw you could also type `genNode` instead of using the character class notation `[g][e][n][N][o][d][e]`

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/36N9cw? Do you need to replace the match, too?

Comment: @Thefourthbird no, I updated my request, now it is more clear, I just want `'['` and `']'` gone in all cases

Comment: Like https://ideone.com/ydIyzU? `print(re.sub(r'(genNode\()\[([0-9,]+)](\))', r'\1\2\3', line))`

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Then like this perhaps `(genNode\()\[(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\](?=\))`https://regex101.com/r/vaxDcU/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
re.sub(r'(genNode\()\[([^]]+)\]', r'\1\2', line)
```

- `(genNode\()` matches `genNode(` and put it in captured group 1
- `\[` matches literal `[`
- `([^]]+)` matches upto next `]`, and put it in captured group 2
- `\]` matches literal `]`

In the replacement, we've used the captured groups only i.e. dropped `[` and `]`.

---

You can get rid of the first captured group by using a *zero-width positive lookbehind* to match the portion before `[`:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=genNode\()\[([^]]+)\]', r'\1', line)
```

---

**Example:**

```
In [444]: line = "assert Solution().oddEvenList(genNode([2,1,3,5,6,4,7])) == genNode([2,3,6,7,1,5,4]), 'Example 2'"                                                                                         

In [445]: re.sub(r'(genNode\()\[([^]]+)\]', r'\1\2', line)                                                                                                                                                  
Out[445]: "assert Solution().oddEvenList(genNode(2,1,3,5,6,4,7)) == genNode(2,3,6,7,1,5,4), 'Example 2'"

In [446]: re.sub(r'(?<=genNode\()\[([^]]+)\]', r'\1', line)                                                                                                                                                 
Out[446]: "assert Solution().oddEvenList(genNode(2,1,3,5,6,4,7)) == genNode(2,3,6,7,1,5,4), 'Example 2'"
```

---

FWIW, using typical non-greedy pattern `.*?` instead of `[^]]+` would work as well:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=genNode\()\[(.*?)\]', r'\1', line)
```

Comment: so the second parameter `r'\1\2'` means we only take the pattern's two group, so that we skipped the `'['` and `']'` that are not included in any group, is that right?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Spot on.

Comment: So, if additionally, If I want to add `'['` and `']'` (reverse operation), I can try the regex pattern, the use `r'\1\[\2\]'` to in `re.sub`?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Nope; no escaping: `r'[\1]'`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `[g][e][n][N][o][d][e][(]` you could write `getNode\(`

The current character class that you use `[0-9\,\s]*` matches 0+ times any of the listed which could also for example match only comma's and does not make sure that there are comma separated digits.

To match the comma delimiter integers, you could match 1+ digits with a repeating group to match a comma and 1+ digits.

At the end use a positive lookahead to assert for the closing parenthesis or capture it in group 3 and also use that in the replacement.

With this pattern use `r'\1\2` as the replacement.

```
(genNode\()\[(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\](?=\))
```

**Explanation**

- `(genNode\()` Capture in group 1 matching `genNode(`
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `\d+(?:,\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and repeat 0+ times a comma and 1+ digits (to also support a single digit)
- `)` Close group 2
- `\]` Match `]`
- `(?=\))` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a closing parenthesis `)`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ah0mL7) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/20G9Kj/1/)

**For example**

```
import re

regex = r"(genNode\()\[(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\](?=\))"
line = "assert Solution().oddEvenList(genNode([2,1,3,5,6,4,7])) == genNode([2,3,6,7,1,5,4]), 'Example 2'"
result = re.sub(regex, r"\1\2", line)

if result:
    print (result)
```

**Result**

```
assert Solution().oddEvenList(genNode(2,1,3,5,6,4,7)) == genNode(2,3,6,7,1,5,4), 'Example 2'
```